# Strange E-Mail Template behaviour in Outlook due to "misalignedColumns"

Tags: outlook, html-email

I've completed an E-Mail Template that has alternating rows containing blocks of two and one size blocks:

```
[--][-]
[-][--]
[--][-]
[-][--]
```

I've saved the source code from Outlook and opened it in a browser. So I managed to narrow down the problem to the following (auto generated - thx old buddy, Outlook!) area of code:

```
// EXAMPLES OF THE LAST TWO ROWS
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

<!--[if !supportMisalignedColumns]-->
<tr height="0">
  <td width="256" style="border:none"></td>
  <td width="198" style="border:none"></td>
  <td width="256" style="border:none"></td>
</tr>
<!--[endif]-->
```

Due to the width of those `td` Elements, the whole `table` loses its correct dimensions. When I erase those lines in Firefox, the `table` renders perfectly.

Is there a possibility to prevent this behaviour by changing the markup? Why does Outlook add this `tr` anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never had any issues with Outlook doing this, so I'm not sure about why. I can share my method though, it may be what you are doing, otherwise it could be worth a try to see if it gives you a different result.

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
  <tr>
    <td width="200"><!-- set col 1 -->
    </td>
    <td width="200"><!-- set col 2 -->
    </td>
    <td width="200"><!-- set col 3 -->
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="400" colspan="2" bgcolor="#454545"><!-- col 1 -->
      content
    </td>
    <td width="200"><!-- col 2 + 3 -->
      content
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="200"><!-- col 1 + 2 -->
      content
    </td>
    <td width="400" colspan="2" bgcolor="#454545"><!-- col 3 -->
      content
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You'll notice the empty first row. Setting the cols there is what forces the colspans to behave.

Comment: Although this was neither the main problem nor the main solution, you gave an important hint to solve the thing. I had to additionally set the the `colspan="2"` containers to `width: 100%;`. That's ugly, but it did the trick.